# Недопереведено описание привилегий

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, привилегии

Вот [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=all):

> 4,000 | trusted user | Expanded editing, deletion and undeletion privileges
>
> 15 | flag posts | Bring content to the attention of the community via flags
>
> 10 | create wiki posts Create answers that can be easily edited by most users

Comment: Кстати, не понимаю, в чем смысл привилегии community wiki. Понтов за такой ответ автор не получает, само по себе "that can be easily edited" - странная вещь, не мотивирующая от слова никак. Смысл в CW-ответах есть только в FAQ, но чтобы делать FAQ, 10 репы как-то на удивление недостаточно.

Comment: Важное замечание, перевод не должен ломать разметку (что произошло сейчас). То есть как термин, так и перевод должны быть в одну строку.

Comment: Это просто плохая разметка, не рассчитанная на несколько строк. А перевод должен правильно передавать смысл.

Comment: Согласен, но на сегодняшний день путь наименьшего сопротивления (читать: самой быстрой реализации) - предоставить строки, которые не длиннее самой длинной на английском.

Comment: Прошелся по всем привилегиям, поправил недочеты. [Пожалуйста, проверяйте](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я добавил ответ с предлагаемыми правками.

Answer (score 3):

```
trusted user
```

Как

```
проверенный участник
```

> Expanded editing, deletion and undeletion privileges

Как

> Полные привилегии правки, удаления и восстановления

---

```
flag posts
```

Как

```
Отмечать тревогой
```

> Bring content to the attention of the community via flags

Как

> Обратить внимание сообщества на содержимое сигналом тревоги

---

```
create wiki posts
```

Как

```
Общие сообщения
```

> Create answers that can be easily edited by most users

Как

> Создавать редактируемые сообществом сообщения

Answer (score 1):

"Задавать и отвечать" - "Спрашивать и отвечать" лучше.

"Начинать конкурс" - "Начинать конкурсы" лучше. Везде в остальном мн.ч.: "..чаты", "..сообщения", "..голоса".

Кроме того, половина привилегий сформулирована глаголами ("Создавать чаты", а не "Создание чатов"), половина существительными ("Общение в чатах", а не "Общаться в чатах"). Стоит ли это привести к единой форме?

Comment: Я пытался использовать глагол везде, где хватает места. Использовал «задавать», потому что «задать вопрос», а не «спросить вопрос». Как вы считаете, какая форма лучше множественная или единственная?

Comment: Либо "спрашивать и отвечать", либо "задавать вопросы и отвечать", но "задавать и отвечать" - это.. странно. По форме - я за множественную, иначе получится "общение в чате" (как будто он один) и т.п.

Comment: Поправил. «Отмечать тревогой» – на мой взгляд, единственное число лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю как-то так:

> 4,000 | благонадёжный пользователь | Расширенные привилегии редактирования, удаления и восстановления
>
> 15 | тревога | Уведомляйте сообщество о проблемах с помощью кнопки "Тревога"
>
> 10 | вики-посты | Создавайте ответы, которые легко могут быть отредактированы большинством пользователей

Comment: вики-посты переведены как «общие вопросы и ответы»